# PhpStorm code inspection returns "Illegal array key type float"

Tags: php, phpstorm

In PhpStorm I get warning about illegal array key type but I can't figure out what illegal about `$size[$factor]`.

> Illegal array key type float

This is my code:

```
    $size       = array(' kB', ' MB', ' GB', ' TB', ' PB', ' EB', ' ZB', ' YB');
    $factor     = round((strlen($kbytes) - 1) / 3);
    $sizereturn = sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $kbytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$size[$factor];
    $sizereturn = str_replace('.', ',', $sizereturn);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`round()` function returns float.

Valid keys for an array element access should be integers and strings.

Try casting it to `int` first, e.g.

```
$factor     = (int)round((strlen($kbytes) - 1) / 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$size` array is a simple array which has `0, 1, 2...,7` integer indexes and the one you assign is a float. Use type casting to convert it first into `integer` then use it.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, it's worth noting that it's just a PhpStorm feature to alert about potential bugs. PHP itself, being a loosely typed language, does not complaint or care about array key types [as long as they're scalars](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func) and will just cast to a proper type:

```
var_dump([
    2.0 => 'Red',
    3.1 => 'Green',
    'Kittens' => 'Blue',
]);

class Foo
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}
var_dump([
    (string)new Foo() => 'This is valid too',
]);

var_dump([
    new Foo()      => 'Invalid key', // Warning: Illegal offset type
    range(1, 2)    => 'Invalid key', // Warning: Illegal offset type
    new Datetime() => 'Invalid key', // Warning: Illegal offset type
]);
```

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(3) "Red"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Green"
  ["Kittens"]=>
  string(4) "Blue"
}
array(1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  string(17) "This is valid too"
}
array(0) {
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/KinNL)

Answer (score 0):

I think casting the result is not the optimal approach.
use PHPDoc comment instead:

```
/** @var int $factor
$factor = round((strlen($kbytes) - 1) / 3);
```